# Does the Informatica Cloud connector for Marketing Cloud exist?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, informatica

We have Informatica cloud in our organisation as well as Salesforce Marketing Cloud. I have seen several articles referencing a Marketing Cloud connector in Informatica but cannot find any such connector in the tool. Has this connector been retired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documentation explains a bit more on Informatica's connector. It is setup similar to other 3rd party integrations that leverage the Marketing Cloud API. E.g. ReturnPath, etc.

https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/6/IC_Spring2017_SalesforceMarketingCloudConnectorGuide_en.pdf

This requires your Marketing Cloud admin to create an Installed Package in Setup > Apps > Installed Packages.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm

Once the Installed Package is created you will provide the client id/secret and other credentials to allow Informatica to connect to your Marketing Cloud instance.